# Flutter Container not wrapping to size of container when alignment property is used

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a container A and a container B such that container A contains container B.
I expect the the container A to wrap itself to the size of the child ie. container B as a container is defined in Flutter doc.

It works as expected and the container A size wraps just to fit the Container B. Very well

However, when alignment property is used on the container A, the Container A extends full height without honouring the height of the container B.

Here is my code :

```
Container(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
            child : Container(child: SizedBox(width:30, height: 300,), color: Colors.green,),
            width: 60,
            color: Colors.blue,
          )
```

How can I use alignment property of the container expecting normal behaviour?

[image]

Comment: I want the parent ie. Container A to be of the same height of child. so it's 300 here. However, the height can vary and would not be constant.

Comment: sorry i dont get is: parent has `width: 60` and the child that has no scrolling has `width:100` - it does not make much sense, what actually do you want to achieve?

Comment: You can disregard the width here, please. The width is not the question. The height is. I want the height of the parent container to be same as child container with the alignment property in use.

Comment: @AkashGorai How do you want to align child to a parent if parent has no size? What do you expect the parent widget without a size will do when you tell him to align its child to anywhere?

Comment: LonelyWolf, I edited the child container width to 30. My parent has a width of 60 as above and height should be wrapped to that of child(not constant). How can I have my child aligning to the left of the container?Currently it gets centered when a column is used instead of Container as child with alignment property omitted. When, used with the container with no alignment property, the child container fills the parent and doesn't honor its own size. What am I doing wrong? Please correct me.

Comment: Ok I got it now.. The parent container always have to have size either you hardcode it or expand it that is your choice but it needs to be some size to be able to align its child. without alignment flutter doesn't know where to draw the child so it makes the size to highest amount in your case 60x300. When you add alignment without parent height or width then flutter failsafe feature expand the parent to give it some size to be able to align its child... hope that make sense

Comment: Yeah I understood that now. I also learnt that it's a very bad idea to use a Container without a parent. Should be wrapped in some row or column. But, how do i get through this? I want my child element to stick to left with variable height and have a breather space to its right of the same height again.

Comment: You will have to make more sense to it... Give us some example or something.. But I believe you want to use row where it's children is only 1 widget. That will give you result what you want I guess... Make some sketch if not

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212267/discussion-between-akash-gorai-and-lonelywolf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to chat conversation this is the required outcome

```
Container( 
color: Colors.red, 
child: Row( 
children: <Widget>[ 
Container( 
height: 300, 
width: 30, 
color: Colors.green, 
) 
], 
), 
)
```

> I have a second question on this regard..if you can answer. What if i
>   reverse my case and would want to have my child align to right and
>   have a breather space to its left?

Add `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end` inside your row

Comment: I was thinking of the same for the second part . Thank you!

Comment: `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end` in your row will align row children to the right... which means your green container will be on the right and your 'breather' on the left...